# How to append newly inserted records information on jsp page without refreshing the page?

Tags: sql, ajax, jsp

I wrote list.jsp program it is just retrieving records from the oracle database. I embed this query in preparedstatement

```
     select * from emp orderby sal;
```

When i am inserting any new records in emp table, list.jsp not showing new records until refresh the page (list.jsp).

here my query is..

```
   how to append these newly inserted record's information to the list.jsp 
  automatically without refreshing or reloading entire page by using ajax ?
```

Comment: You can use ajax and javascript (without reloading the entire page) and simply add the new item (as HTML objects) to the list of the other ones.

Comment: You have to perform some event to display new records. Event could be page load, click, scroll etc. Or you can do a Ajax call in regular intervals which could be quite expensive.

Comment: thankyou..can you mention ajax code ?  (i jst want to append the new records instead of reloading entire records again)